# SQL insert nulls columns

Tags: powershell

I have a `foreach` loop which adds pricing to a column one at a time (every 5 mins). The problem is as soon as I populate one column, it nulls the rest. As the `foreach` progresses my new values end up on a new row E.g.

```
|USD |GBP |EURO|
|1.5 |Null|Null|
|Null|1.2 |Null|
|Null|Null|1.8 |
```

I'd like the `foreach` to put them on the same row, i.e. overwriting null

```
|USD |GBP |EURO|
|1.5 |1.2 |1.8 |
```

```
foreach ($curr in $currs) {
    $SQLPC = "INSERT INTO dbo.Percentages($curr) VALUES ('$curr.price')"
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $SQLDatabase -Query $SQLPC -ServerInstance $SQLInstance -Username $SQLUsername -Password $SQLPassword
}
```

Comment: Your inserting each value as a new record. You need to insert all in one statement: `INSERT INTO dbo.Percentages (USD, GBP, EURO) VALUES ('1.5', '1.2', '1.8');`.

Comment: What Ansgar said is correct, you can probably chuck this in a for loop and just increment by 3 each time so the values would be  $curr[0].price $curr[1].price $curr[2].price etc.

Comment: Where the `$currs` object comes from? Please [edit] your question to complete [mcve] rules. Adding output from `$currs|Get-Member -MemberType Properties` as well as from `$currs` should suffice.